# upload and gzip file on windows can't find path

Tags: windows, scala, playframework, gzip

I'm new to scala and have taken over a project which is taking an upload and zipping it before passing it off to s3.

The file is created in

```
case Some(activityId: Long) =>
        val tempFilePath = "/tmp/tack.%d".format(activityId)
        val gzipTempFilePath = tempFilePath + ".gz"
        val tempFile = new File(tempFilePath)
        gpsTackFile.ref.moveTo(tempFile, true)
        val fileName = Activity.tackFilePathFromId(activityId)
        val mimeType = "text/plain"
        val f = compressAndUpload(tempFilePath, fileName, mimeType)
```

The compress and upload uses gzip on the command line, and fails because it can't find the tempFilePath

```
 def compressAndUpload(tempFilePath: String, dstFileName: String, mimeType: String): Future[Boolean] = {
    "gzip -9 " + tempFilePath ! match {
```

I thought the problem may have been due to how window and linux handle files differently, but trying to use `"""/tmp/tack.%d"""` didn't fix the issue (that is what I found when trying to properly escape the string for windows).

The error I get is `gzip: /tmp/tack.1024.gz: No such file or directory`

Comment: `/tmp/` is a common directory in unix filesystems meant for temporary files, but it won't be present on Windows (`/`is the root of the file system, sort of like `C:` in Windows, but not really).  If you want to store to a temp folder on Windows, see http://www.askvg.com/where-does-windows-store-temporary-files-and-how-to-change-temp-folder-location/ for where you might do that.  I would recommend you modify your code to allow you to pass in a file location, or make it determine where to save the file dynamically based on OS.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @soong comment in the response, I added a `TMP_DIR` as a global in our bash script like this

```
case $OS in
    'Windows_NT')
    TMP_PATH="c:$TMP"
    ;;
    *)
    TMP_PATH='/tmp'
    ;;
esac

export TMP_PATH
```

This works for Windows 10, I can't comment on other versions. The drive letter was needed at the beginning as it isn't included in the `$TMP` variable